# How to fix ERROR_NOACCESS = -7 in google pepper plugin API

Tags: google-nativeclient

From NACL SDk examples i am trying to run socket example. Example available at ..\nacl_sdk\pepper_34\examples\api\socket

While i am trying to connect to google.com:80 using TCP socket, given error is flashed:

```
 Resolving ...
 Resolve failed with status-7
```

After googling i found ERROR_NOACCESS = -7, Indicates failure due to insufficient privileges.
Does anyone come across this error?

What can be the reason for that, and what is the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use TCP/UDP sockets in a NaCl app, you have to create a packaged app in the Chrome Web Store since these permissions require an accept gesture from the user.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network

"Apps permission socket with subrule tcp-connect is required for Connect(); subrule tcp-listen is required for Listen()." - https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_t_c_p_socket